# Play framework Leon Salat Model Form Mapping

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, salat

I'm creating a scala application using Play framework and mongoDB. I manage to have the connections up using [Leon Play-Salat](https://github.com/leon/play-salat). I have a model

```
case class Person(
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  fname: String,
  mname: String,
  lname: String
)
```

In my controller I need to map it to a form

```
val personForm: Form[Person] = Form(

// Defines a mapping that will handle Contact values
mapping(
  "id" -> of[ObjectId],
  "fname" -> nonEmptyText,
  "mname" -> text,
  "lname" -> nonEmptyText     
)(Person.apply)(Person.unapply))
```

How do I map the ObjectID to the form ? I'm getting error Object not found for the ObjectId.

Comment: First of all you have to annotate the `id` field with `@Key("_id")`. Otherwise the field won't be mapped to the mongo's default id field.
I think it would help if you pasted the stack trace of the error, because it's not clear when the error occurs.

Comment: On the other hand it's not very useful to reveal the `id` field on a form unless it's of a type more human readable than `ObjectID`.

Comment: I need the ID for the read and edit function. On the new form the ID should be automatically generated by Mongodb.

Answer (score 3):

Manage to get it working

```
val personForm: Form[Person] = Form(
// Defines a mapping that will handle Contact values
mapping(
  "id" -> ignored(new ObjectId),
  "fname" -> nonEmptyText,
  "mname" -> text,
  "lname" -> nonEmptyText     
)(Person.apply)(Person.unapply))
```

I'm trying to do a CRUD function thus need the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Found using own constructor and deconstructor is better

```
val personForm: Form[Person] = Form(
  mapping(
    "fname" -> nonEmptyText,
    "mname" -> text,
    "lname" -> nonEmptyText
  )((fname, mname, lname) => Person(new ObjectId, fname, mname, lname))
  ((person: Person) => Some((person.fname, person.mname, person.lname)))      )
```